# How to identify if an executable file was compiled from C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, exe, executable

My college professor asked me how to identify if a `.exe` file was created using C or C++?

Does anyone know how to identify that?

Comment: Do you need to identify which files are executable from a C or C++ program, _or_ are you trying to figure out which language was used to create an executable?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  The earliest C++ compilers worked by translating the C++ code into C, then invoking a C compiler to complete the task.  So would an executable that was compiled in this fashion count as "compiled C" or "compiled C++"?

Comment: I guess you could examine which libraries are used - though some libraries can be used by both languages.

Comment: This would require a lot of skill (and a decent amount of time too). C/C++ is the written text that we understand. The executable is in binary. The way to work it out would be to disassemble the code into the assembly language (for the cpu the exe file is supposed to be used on); then read through the assembly file for clues. In practice compilers will write differently for different languages, so someone skilled with compilers would be able to tell the difference if there's enough code.

Comment: Let's say you have a way to determine this, how would you use this information?

Comment: @Déjàvu c++ code doesn't have to use the standard library

Answer (score 5):

The easy approach: If your binary has not been stripped of symbols, its C++ components will include mangled names, e.g. `?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@`, `.?AVbad_typeid@@`, or `_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev`. A C binary should not have mangled symbols. On the other hand, symbols starting with `_R` strongly suggest [Rust name mangling](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2603-rust-symbol-name-mangling-v0.html).

If you don't have *any* symbols, you can use imports or strings to get hints, but you're starting to get into the realm of guesswork:

If the binary is a C++ binary from MSVC, it will be linked against either the MSVC++ runtime or another C++ runtime (e.g. libstdc++). As a result, you'll either see the literal string `"Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library"` embedded in the binary, or you'll see a file named similar to `msvcp###.dll` (note the *P* in the name) in the imports table.

If you're using something like msys/mingw/cygwin, you'll still see strings related to the C++ runtime library, but the exact wording will be different. I observed `GLIBCXX_3.4` as well as some mangled names even in a stripped binary from clang++, but your outcomes may vary. Other hints are the names of C++ exceptions or classes, e.g. `basic_string` or `bad_typeid`.

Failing that, you can look for strings that look like mangled names (see first paragraph); I looked at a few C++ binaries on my system and even though their symbol tables were stripped, they still had tons of mangled names showing up as strings.

Other giveaways are tables of pointers that point into the code section, which might form virtual dispatch tables, or [Windows RTTI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/run-time-type-information?view=msvc-170). On windows x86, expect a large number of these functions to take a pointer input from ECX/RCX (which is `this`).

Note that this is not foolproof; if so inclined I could create a C++ binary and then carefully obfuscate all of these hints. A true reverse engineering tool, such as Ghidra, can help you make these determinations as well as many more insights, once you know how to use it responsibly and effectively.

Comment: How does an executable have symbols? They're present in assembly code to assist at that layer, but once it's assembled those become numerical adresses, right?

Comment: @Elliott Two ways - a program is free to export symbols other than its entry point; this allows it to also be dynamically loaded into another process, at least on win32 (not sure if it hits undefined behavior, but it's definitely possible from the aspect of LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress with an exe that has exports). Second, a program can retain a symbol table for the benefit of debugging.